# Information why RegEx did not match

Tags: regex

Is there a way to find out what was the reason why a regular expression did not match? Maybe, what was the first character until that the regex would have matched if the rest would have matched as well?

I do not want to check a regular expression I created but I want to display to a user why my application failed to parse a line.

**UPDATE 1**: Added additional information.

Comment: try regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) to build and test your RegEx.

Comment: @Hannes [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) Also users with 7 rep [don't have downvote privilege yet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).